# Multiple Windows 7 installations from Grub

Tags: ubuntu, boot, grub, boot-loader

I have the following disk configuration:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 750.2 GB, 750156374016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 91201 cylinders, total 1465149168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x28ec8922

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

Disk /dev/sdb: 256.1 GB, 256060514304 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 31130 cylinders, total 500118192 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x72654d40

Device     Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2          206848    62914559    31353856    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb3        62914560   167772159    52428800    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb4       167774206   284358655    58292225    5  Extended
/dev/sdb5       167774208   168357887      291840   83  Linux
/dev/sdb6       168359936   218357759    24998912   83  Linux
/dev/sdb7       218359808   268357631    24998912   83  Linux
/dev/sdb8       268359680   284358655     7999488   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdc: 24.0 GB, 24015495168 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 2919 cylinders, total 46905264 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x28ec8923

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
```

On `/dev/sdb`, I have two windows 7 installations, /dev/sdb1 is the Windows System Partition, `/dev/sdb2` is the first Windows 7 installation, `/dev/sdb3` is the second Windows 7 installation. The rest of the partitions are Ubuntu 14.04, and I am using Grub. The grub menu lists the windows loader only, and I have to go into the windows loader to select one of the Windows installations to boot from. Is it possible to list both the windows installations in the grub menu?

I tried with the following Grub Custom Menu, but when I run grub-update, it does not detect any of the operating systems:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0

menuentry "Ubuntu" {
recordfail
load_video
insmod gzio
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='hd1,msdos5'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root /dev/sdb5
linux /vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic root=UUID=/dev/sdb5 ro recovery nomodeset
initrd  /initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
}

menuentry "Windows Lab" {
insmod ntfs
set root='hd1,1'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root /dev/sdb2
chainloader+1
}

menuentry "Windows Personal" {
insmod ntfs
set root='hd1,1'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set-root /dev/sdb3
chainloader+1
}
```

How do I get the `grub` menu to list both the Windows 7 installations?

Comment: I guess this is windows question, you would rather ask it in this site: http://superuser.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Windows